# What is the difference between torch.cuda.amp.GradScaler vs torch.cuda.amp.grad_scaler.GradScaler?

Tags: pytorch

As the question says. I saw different convergence rate using one over the other. I did not find anything in the documentation about "torch.cuda.amp.grad_scaler.GradScaler". The documentation only mentions "torch.cuda.amp.GradScaler". Are there any differences between the two in terms of implementation or default parameters?

Comment: what is your pytorch version ?

Comment: Pytorch version 1.10